# how to add drivers for e1000e in ubuntu server installer

Tags: server, subiquity

I currently deploy my systems with ubuntu server 20.04 and add packages based on this script https://gist.github.com/creatldd1/eec887f3f8a0bf48e0e9dec1598b8614rev

My new hardware includes an intel I219-LM (rev11) as a network adapter, which is not detected anymore. I can fix this by building and installing a package from https://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/e1000e%20historic%20archive/ after the installation, but when I try that within the installation, I failes with

```
 2022-04-10 12:48:36,252 ERROR root:39 finish: subiquity/Late/run/command_10: FAIL: Command '['systemd-cat', '--level-prefix=false', '--identifier=subiquity_log.2288', 'sh', '-c', 'curtin in-target --target=/target -- dpkg -i --force-all /awrepo/gp/*.deb']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
 2022-04-10 12:48:36,252 ERROR root:39 finish: subiquity/Late/run: FAIL: Command '['systemd-cat', '--level-prefix=false', '--identifier=subiquity_log.2288', 'sh', '-c', 'curtin in-target --target=/target -- dpkg -i --force-all /awrepo/gp/*.deb']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
 2022-04-10 12:48:36,252 ERROR subiquity.server.server:414 top level error
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/snap/subiquity/3119/lib/python3.8/site-packages/subiquity/server/controllers/cmdlist.py", line 106, in _run
     await self.run()
   File "/snap/subiquity/3119/lib/python3.8/site-packages/subiquitycore/context.py", line 148, in decorated_async
     return await meth(self, **kw)
   File "/snap/subiquity/3119/lib/python3.8/site-packages/subiquity/server/controllers/cmdlist.py", line 70, in run
     await arun_command(
   File "/snap/subiquity/3119/lib/python3.8/site-packages/subiquitycore/utils.py", line 85, in arun_command
     raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, cmd)
 subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['systemd-cat', '--level-prefix=false', '--identifier=subiquity_log.2288', 'sh', '-c', 'curtin in-target --target=/target -- dpkg -i --force-all /awrepo/gp/*.deb']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Not sure what happens there
Additionally that step requires also dkms and build-essentials installed in the server installation step

Also this seems to be quite over overkill, so is there an easier ( maybe even official) way to add drivers to the installation?

EDIT: My first post was unclear, so I made it more specific

Comment: "Issues"? What issues? "Ubuntu server" Which? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: *e1000e* is included in all recent; that is, not end-of-life Ubuntu versions.